# Push segue in SWRevealViewController not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, segue, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using the SWRevealViewController library for a side menu within my main view. Side menu consists of tableView.  I have followed [This tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/)

[image]

DashBoard Controller in `frontView` and `tableView` is rear a view.
Route Assistant is view which segue with `SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController` class. ViewAllTripsViewController opens on "Install Now" button. In `ViewAllTripsViewController` there is button (Float button ) which connect to `ROuteAssistant` VC via Push segue. when `ROuteAssistant` open with push segue , hamburger menu doesn't work (not showing any Side menu).

How can I show this?

I have tried this

```
if self.revealViewController() != nil {
            menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }

        else
       {
            print("Some Problem")
        }
```

when I select RouteAssistant From tableView(menu) is work properly but when is get access by button it goes to else condition

Comment: which one is not work'

Comment: @ Anbu.Karthik hamburgerMenu Button on RouteAssistant View when it is segue(PUSH ) from button(in View All Trip VC)

Comment: I think you choose custom option.  select show option check my edit .

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see any NavigationController in your storyboard.
Add a Navigation Controller then set to initialController and connect to your rootViewController (set as RootViewController)

For push Programmatically check My answer : 
[Push To ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y29kI.png)

Don't Forget these things:

**1. Your storyboard identifier is correct.

2. The root view have navigation Controller.**

**Edit :**

Your storyboard initialViewController should be like this,
**Note:** I think you are choose ' Custom' option. Select the right one, ' Show' option.

[image]

Comment: which view should be embedded into navigationViewController : reavelViewController or DashboardView Controller(frontView)

Comment: Before "reavelViewController" add a Navigation controller, dafault it embedded a TableviewController , just delete the same. Control drag and connect to ' reavelViewController' set as RootViewController. Then set Navigation controller to initialViewController (drag the arrow on to NavigationController)

Comment: follow ur steps, still not working. Problem is when RouteAssistance View is show, hamburger menu doest show any SideBarMenu(tableView)

Comment: At first check with one or 2 viewcontroller then check it will work ? If you push from storyboard no need to do the same in programatically